# In a multi header dataframe, how to select a column with one of the tuple values of the header, and the rest being anything?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the header has 3 values. I want to select the columns of my dataframe where I know one of the values, but the other two values can be anything.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
df[slice(None), slice(None), "My header"]
```

When I do, I get an error that this is an "invalid key"

I've also tried this with loc:

```
df.loc[:, slice(None), slice(None), "My header"]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post an example of your dataframe.  I like use .loc with axis parameter.  Try this: `df.loc(axis=1)[:,:,"My header"]`

Comment: Hello, as you are new on stackoverflow take few minutes to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to improve it, like giving some example of your data, what you're trying to acheive. Thanks

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks for the tip, but that didn't work unfortunately. The error message is: pandas.errors.UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (3), lexsort depth (1)'

My df is actually one I just read from a csv, so not sure if I can post an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know if this is the "best" solution, but what did end up working for me was to first sort the headers using:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

And then using slice(None):

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), slice(None), "MyHeader3")]
```

Hope this helps anyone else!

Another solution:

```
df[[x for x in df.columns if 'header3' in x]]
```

Not sure which is more efficient though.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using df.xs("My header", level=2, axis=1) as this allows selection by level without having to specify a tuple with all the column names.

See [https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-select-columns-from-pandas-multiindex/#:~:text=In%20conclusion%2C%20selecting%20columns%20from,datasets%20with%20multi%2Ddimensional%20data.](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-select-columns-from-pandas-multiindex/#:%7E:text=In%20conclusion%2C%20selecting%20columns%20from,datasets%20with%20multi%2Ddimensional%20data.)